# Cannot compile GLFW with premake 5

Tags: c, glfw, premake

I'm pretty new to this so please don't be too harsh if the error is something really simple. I am trying to compile GLFW from their official repository using premake, but every single time it returns the following error:

```
"==== Building glfw (debug) ===="
"context.c"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -MD -MP -D_GLFW_WIN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -g -o obj/glfw/debug/context.o -MF obj/glfw/debug/context.d -c src/context.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [glfw.make:170: obj/glfw/debug/context.o] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:30: glfw] Error 2
```

The command used is just `make`

I've been researching this for days but I'm not sure if it's some obscure error only one guy from like 10 years ago had or I just didn't type in the right thing, but I couldn't find any fix. I expected GLFW just to compile without any errors. My premake5.lua file is:

```lua
workspace "glfw"
    configurations { "debug", "release" }

project "glfw"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C"

    targetdir("bin/glfw/")
    objdir("obj/glfw/")

    files
    {
        "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
        "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
        "src/context.c",
        "src/init.c",
        "src/input.c",
        "src/monitor.c",

        "src/null_init.c",
        "src/null_joystick.c",
        "src/null_monitor.c",
        "src/null_window.c",

        "src/platform.c",
        "src/vulkan.c",
        "src/window.c",

        "src/win32_init.c",
        "src/win32_joystick.c",
        "src/win32_module.c",
        "src/win32_monitor.c",
        "src/win32_time.c",
        "src/win32_thread.c",
        "src/win32_window.c",
        "src/wgl_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c"
    }

    defines
    {
        "_GLFW_WIN32",
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
    }

    filter "configurations:debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"
```

I generated Makefile with the command `premake5 gmake2` which ran successfully with this output:

```
Building configurations...
Running action 'gmake2'...
Generated glfw.make...
Done (43ms).
```

I'm using VSCode 1.85.2 as my editor of choice and GNU Make 4.2.1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `make` is trying to compile a C source file with a compiler named `cc`.  This is a conventional name for the C compiler on a Unix system, but your Windows machine does not have a compiler going by that name, or if it does, then that compiler is not in the executable search path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works completely fine now (just renamed gcc to cc)

Comment: @JohnBollinger if you post this as answer, it can be accepted as such.